# Well-posedness of wave equation in Sobolev spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Let  $$ u_{tt}-\Delta u=0\;\;\;\mbox{in}\;\;\;\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,t)\;\;\;\;\;\;(1.1)$$

$$u=f\;,u_t=g\;\;\mbox{in}\;\;\;\mathbb{R}^n\times\{t=0\}\;\;(1.2)$$

Defining $u_t=v$, the problem $(1.1)-(1.2)$ can be written
$$U_t(t)=AU(t),\;\;U(0)=\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
   f \\
   g \\
  \end{array}
\right)\;\;\;(1.3)$$
where $U=\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
   u \\
   v \\
  \end{array}
\right)$ and $A=\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
   0&1\\\Delta&0\\
  \end{array}
\right)$.

My problem is to show that $(1.3)$ is well-posedness in $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)\times H^{s-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but how to interpret $(1.3)$?